# Linux mint bug - Theme changed (and cant change back) and slow loading drivers

Tags: linux, linux-mint, themes, cinnamon

It's not the easiest thing to explain, but basically I have linux mint 15 (Nadia) on my desktop, running Cinnamon.

When I started it up the other day, the layout of the UI was different (taskbar at the bottom instead of top, the theme has changed (white instead of black, and different icons), all of the menus are different (different layout, and shows different information).

I also noticed that it seems to take a long time for my keyboard and mouse drivers to load now.

I don't know if somebody has changed something, without me knowing or if it's a bug, but it seems more like a bug as I can't seem to change the theme etc back.

Thanks for any assistance!
Nick

EDIT: Forgot to mention I also tried resetting cinnamon with gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I know exactly what caused this, but reinstalling mint over itself (so I didn't have to reinstall apps / copy all of my Documents back on) fixed the issue.

If anyone else happens to have this (seemingly rare) problem, this is no doubt the easiest way to fix it.